# where to keep pictures in Eclipse Project

Tags: html, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have simple Html page in my eclipe J2EE project and I am using Tomcat Server to deploy it..problem is when I am running the project using eclipse internal web browser all the pictures are getting visible..but when I am deploying the same using System Default External browser the images are not getting loaded?/

```
<img src="E:\\Wallpapers\\12.jpg" align="left" alt="Scene1" >
```

I have all other images in my disk..where should I keep the images to solve the prblem?/

Answer (score 0):

You should place your images in your web content folder which is in parallel to the WEB-INF folder and refer them using relative urls

```
<img src="12.jpg" align="left" alt="Scene1" >
```

Comment: Still My Browser not displaying it..
/ok MY Directory structure is --

My Project->WebContent->WEB-INF
and I Copied the images directly into WebContent folder where my Html and other jsp pages reside..is it ok??